# javascript regex to match multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex, multiple-matches

my multiple string is something like below

```
###
some content
that I need to match
and might have some special character in it such as | <> []
###
```

I am trying to get the content of between hashes. I have tried below regex but it is not matching to it and return null.

```
var regex = /### ((.|\n)*) ###/;
var match= regex.exec(aboveContentAsString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: take out the spaces in the regex

Comment: `### (` tries to match `###` followed by a space. However in your example text, `###` is followed by a line break, so no match. Why do you have the spaces in the expression?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

JavaScript lacks the `s` (singleline/dotall) regex option, but you can workaround it by replacing `.` with `[\s\S]` (match any character that is a whitespace or that is not a whitespace, which basically means match everything). Also, make your quantifier lazy and get rid of the spaces in the pattern, since there's also no `x` (extended) option in JS:

```
var regex = /###([\s\S]*?)###/;
```

Example:

```js
var input = "###\nsome content\nthat I need to match\nand might have some special character in it such as | <> []\n###";

var regex = /###([\s\S]*?)###/;
document.getElementById("output").innerText = regex.exec(input)[1];
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Your original approach could have worked, but I'd add `\r` in there too:

```
var regex = /###((?:.|[\r\n])*?)###/;
```

But I prefer the `[\s\S]` approach since it's shorter and (IMHO) more readable.

Comment: Sidenode: Can be ANY distinct pair, like `[\d\D]`, `[\w\W]`, or even `[^]` (**all but nothing**) :-)

Comment: @dognose beware with `[^]` - I reccomend against it since it "works" only in JS and is not standard regex syntax: in other flavors, the `]` will be interpreted as `\]` and the character class will be unterminated (syntax error).

Comment: Youre right. Regex Hint #25566 recorded :P

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no *Dot-Matches-All-Option* - therefore just use: dot OR whitespace. (first `\s*` to make sure your match does not start with a linebreak - not mandatory ofc.)

```
^###\s*((?:.|\s)*)###$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kSENERogTkLIJxM-)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the regex not to match the three hashes, try something like this: 
`(?![###])[^#]((.|\s)[^#])*`. This uses a negative lookbehind to start matching only when it cannot match `###`. It starts matching and continues until it hits another hash.